# Angular Module injection error while injecting controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and facing a problem injecting controller to an angular app. I am trying to build a single page application where the user can navigate through the pages of a particular application form. While the code for the controllers was in the same JS file, it was working fine. But moving the controllers to a separate file(as in this case, 'js/controllers/pagecontroller.js') is throwing the error below.

Error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/nomod?p0=uwApp.controllers
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=uwApp&p1=Error%3A%2…oogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A19)
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="uwApp">
    <head>

        <!-- SCROLLS -->
        <!-- load bootstrap and fontawesome via CDN -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css" />

        <!-- SPELLS -->
        <!-- load angular and angular route via CDN -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.js"></script>

        <!-- Donut chart api -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/maincontroller.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/pagecontroller.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="mainController">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
'use strict';
    var uwApp = angular.module('uwApp', ['uwApp.controllers','ngRoute'])
    .config(function($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider

            // route for the home page
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            })

            // route for the page
            .when('/acknandagreement', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/loan/acknandagreement.html',
                controller  : 'pageCtrl9'
            })

            // route for the page
            .when('/assetsandliabilities', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/loan/assetsandliabilities.html',
                controller  : 'pageCtrl6'
            })

            // route for the page
            .when('/borrowerinfo', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/loan/borrowerinfo.html',
                controller  : 'pageCtrl3'
            })

            // route for the page
            .when('/employmentinfo', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/loan/employmentinfo.html',
                controller  : 'pageCtrl4'
            })

            // route for the page
            .when('/infoandgovpurpose', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/loan/infoandgovpurpose.html',
                controller  : 'pageCtrl10'
            })

            // route for the page
            .when('/monthlyincomeandche', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/loan/monthlyincomeandche.html',
                controller  : 'pageCtrl5'
            })

            // route for the page
            .when('/morttypeandterm', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/loan/morttypeandterm.html',
                controller  : 'pageCtrl1'
            })

            // route for the page
            .when('/propertyinfoandpurpose', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/loan/propertyinfoandpurpose.html',
                controller  : 'pageCtrl2'
            })

            // route for the page
            .when('/residualapplication', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/loan/residualapplication.html',
                controller  : 'pageCtrl11'
            })

            // route for the page
            .when('/txndetails', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/loan/txndetails.html',
                controller  : 'pageCtrl7'
            })

            // route for the page
            .when('/declarations', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/loan/declarations.html',
                controller  : 'pageCtrl8'
            })
            ;
    });
```

pagecontroller.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('uwApp.controllers')
.controller('pageCtrl1', function($scope) {
    $scope.page = 'morttypeandterm';
})

.controller('pageCtrl2', function($scope) {
    $scope.page = 'propertyinfoandpurpose';
})

.controller('pageCtrl3', function($scope) {
    $scope.page = 'borrowerinfo';
})

.controller('pageCtrl4', function($scope) {
    $scope.page = 'employmentinfo';
})

.controller('pageCtrl5', function($scope) {
    $scope.page = 'monthlyincomeandche';
})

.controller('pageCtrl6', function($scope) {
    $scope.page = 'assetsandliabilities';
})

.controller('pageCtrl7', function($scope) {
    $scope.page = 'txndetails';
})

.controller('pageCtrl8', function($scope) {
    $scope.page = 'declarations';
})

.controller('pageCtrl9', function($scope) {
    $scope.page = 'acknandagreement';
})

.controller('pageCtrl10', function($scope) {
    $scope.page = 'infoandgovpurpose';
})

.controller('pageCtrl11', function($scope) {
    $scope.page = 'residualapplication';
});
```

maincontroller.js

```
'use strict';
angular.module('uwApp.controllers', [])
 .controller('mainController', function($scope) {

});
```

I have no clue why its not working. Please suggest.

Comment: try replacing `angular.module('uwApp.controllers')` with `angular.module('uwApp.controllers', [])` and you can remove the `var uwApp =` no need for that

Comment: uwApp.controllers is not properly defined. Do as @valarmorghulis suggested

Comment: Edited the question with the snippet of maincontroller.

Comment: @chows2603 Please look at the example I provided in my answer as I am fairly sure it will solve your problem.

Comment: @chows2603 Multiple people have correctly answered your question. Please accept one so the question is closed. People put their time into trying to help you, the least you can do is appropriately accept their answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `pageController.js` write like this

```
angular.module('uwApp.controllers', [])
 .controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.page = 'main controller';
})
```

## some Explanation:

Beware that using `angular.module('myModule', [])` will create the module myModule and overwrite any existing module named myModule. Use `angular.module('myModule')` to retrieve an existing module.

Find more [angular docs module](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#module-loading-dependencies)

There is an interesting style guidelines for angular by jonpapa [johnpapa/angular-styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)

Comment: I don't think ng-route's mentioned wrongly. As i said, there's no change in HTML, just the separation of the controller is creating this issue.

Comment: After the change you suggested I am now getting the following error: Argument 'mainController' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: have you written this controller `.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.page = 'main controller';
})` please add this as well

Comment: Yes, its there in a seperate module.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115026/discussion-between-valar-morghulis-and-chows2603).

Comment: an error in maincontroller.js can trigger the module injection error too?

Comment: i have explained it in discussion chat please see that you will get an better idea what is going wrong, and do read the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

I made a working [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/eQ7bbpwOzJVsqJWPrIzC?p=preview) on plnkr from supplied code. There are a couple things I changed:

1) Since your base route will be running `mainController` you should not put it on the `ng-controller` as well.

2) When you are referencing a module, as in the `angular.module('uwApp.controllers')`, the module must first have been defined. The way to define a module is to have brackets for it's dependencies, like `angular.module('uwApp.controllers', [])`.

With those things fixed you do not need to do what I said below.

---

There is no need to inject the controllers through a separate module.

You can change *pagecontroller.js*:

```
angular.module('uwApp.controllers')
```

to...

```
angular.module('uwApp')
```

Then *app.js*:

```
var uwApp = angular.module('uwApp', ['uwApp.controllers','ngRoute'])
```

to...

```
var uwApp = angular.module('uwApp', ['ngRoute'])
```

Comment: the way chows has written is also an valid way.

Comment: @valarmorghulis You're right, I updated it with the actual needed changes.